# Having trouble when trying to upload an svg image to Cloudfare with axios

Tags: javascript, svg, axios, next.js, fetch-api

I'm having issues with svg files while running this code. The pngs and jpgs files are uploading to Cloudfare correctly, but when an svg file appears, it returns this error:

*ERROR 9422: Decode error: image failed to be decoded: Uploaded image must have image/jpeg or image/png content type\n*

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? thanks

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://www.datocms-assets.com/45562/test-image.png",
    { responseType: "stream" }
  );

  const form = new FormData();
  form.append("image", response.data, "test.png");

  try {
    const postRes = await axios.post(
      `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/my-id/images/v1`,
      form,
      {
        headers: {
          ...form.getHeaders(),
          Authorization: `Bearer my-api-key`,
        },
      }
    );
    console.info("response", postRes);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while uploading to cloudflare", error);
  }
};
```

Comment: My guess would be that a SVG is not considered an image by a document. So, the endpoint that you are using is the "image endpoint" -- is there a similar one for other files/documents like HTML -- I would try that.